# Disable cache control in nginx ingress controler for certain response

Tags: nginx, caching, controls, kubernetes-ingress

I have this ingress configuration but all html and json reponse pages dont contain the added header:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ $app }}-ingress
  labels:
    app: {{ $app }} 
    chart: chart-{{ $app }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: {{ $app }}
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "{{ $proxy_body_size }}"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "{{ $proxy_read_timeout }}"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "{{ $proxy_connect_timeout }}"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "{{ $proxy_send_timeout }}"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "{{ $proxy_buffer_size }}"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet : |
        if ($request_uri ~* \.(html|json)) {
           add_header Cache-Control "no-cache,no-store";
        }
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - {{ $alias }}
  rules:
    - host: {{ $alias }}
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: {{ $app }}-service
              servicePort: http-back
```

I want to disable cache control only for html and json content response. When I remove the if ($request_uri ~* .(html|json)) condition, all responses have the added header. So this means that the condition in the configuration-snippet is not correct.

Can you help please?

Comment: What do you mean by `When I remove the if ($request_uri ~* .(html|json)) condition, all responses have the added header.`
Do you remove `add_header` statement as well ?
I think your current `if` statement correctly catch only `.html` and `.json` file - in addition you may want to add `$` sign at the end as `if ( $request_uri ~* \.(html|json)$ )`

Comment: It mean when I remove the condition the Cache Control header is added in all server responses.
I want this header to be added only in html and json responses.
I added the $ at the end but no effect. The header is not added on html and json responses.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue, but your `if` condition seems to work correctly for me.
For clarification, this condition checks if full original request URI has `.html` or `.json` at the end.
For example, for `example.com/a.json` the condition will be true and for `example.com/a` the condition will be false.
Can you provide your sample request URI ?

Comment: I want to add the header Cache control in response. So I think the condition should be applied on the response url and not on the request url. But I dont now wich variable I should use to control the reponse url. Do you now this var? There is a sample of my request and response: 
Request URL: https://sample.com/api/v1/notification/latest?group=ALL 
Response is a json content

Comment: Why do you think this is `json` content ? How do you check it ?
You can find more information about `$request_uri`  [here](https://www.webhosting24.com/understanding-nginx-request_uri/).

Comment: Yes it's a json content. I check it from the response in the browser network console

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and smth like this worked for me:

```
      if ($request_uri ~* \.(?:html|json)$) {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store,no-cache";
        add_header Pragma "no-cache";
      }
```